# Django Exception Type: IntegrityError Exception Value: NOT NULL constraint failed: video_url.p_id

Tags: python, django

I do not add one post. Write me it:
Exception Type: IntegrityError Exception Value: NOT NULL constraint failed: video_url.p_id

I use it in admin.py:

```
....
....
def save_formset(self, request, form, formset, change):
    ...
    super(ArticlesAdmin, self).save_formset(request, form, formset, change)
```

if clear `super(ArticlesAdmin, self).save_formset(request, form, formset, change)`, then job good.

Help me, please? (Sorry, i bad speak english)

Comment: Please update your question to include the code of the entire model admin, and the traceback.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it. Just clear:

```
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
pass
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is answered here [Not NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26727616/not-null-constraint-failed-error) and here [Models NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25964312/not-null-constraint-failed-after-adding-to-models-py)

In summary , add these fields to your model

You must create a migration, where you will specify default value for a new field, since you don't want it to be null. If null is not required, simply add `null=True` and create and run migration.