# 'NOT NULL constraint failed' after adding to models.py

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-migrations

I'm using userena and after adding the following line to my models.py

```
zipcode = models.IntegerField(_('zipcode'),
                                   max_length=5)
```

I get the following error after I hit the submit button on th signup form:

```
IntegrityError at /accounts/signup/
NOT NULL constraint failed: accounts_myprofile.zipcode
```

My question is what does this error mean, and is this related to Userena?

Comment: did you run migrations? Django by default would not pick up changes to models. Moreover, if you do not specify `null=True, blank=True`, it becomes a required field

Comment: Setting null and blank does not change anything. Even deleting the attribute does not help.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

You must create a migration, where you will specify default value for a new field, since you don't want it to be null. If null is not required, simply add `null=True` and create and run migration.

Comment: Note: you may have to delete already present migration files before to run again makemigrations and migrate.

Comment: The migrations don't run after this error occured once.

Comment: @lolesque your solutions worked for me, in my caso I also needed to delete db.sqlite3, thanks!

Answer (score 18):

[coldmind](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2116126/coldmind)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25964444/11573842) is correct but lacks details.

**The `NOT NULL constraint failed` occurs when something tries to set `None` to the `zipcode` property, while it has not been explicitly allowed.**

It usually happens when:

1. Your field has `Null=False` by default, so that the value in the database cannot be `None` (i.e. undefined) when the object is created and saved in the database (this happens after a `objects_set.create()` call or setting the `.zipcode` property and doing a `.save()` call).

   For instance, if somewhere in your code an assignment results in:

   ```py
   model.zipcode = None
   ```

   This error is raised.
2. When creating or updating the database, Django is *constrained* to find a default value to fill the field, because `Null=False` by default. It does not find any because you haven't defined any. So this error can not only happen during code execution but also when creating the database?
3. Note that the same error would be returned if you define `default=None`, or if your default value with an incorrect type, for instance `default='00000'` instead of `00000` for your field (maybe can there be an automatic conversion between char and integers, but I would advise against relying on it. Besides, explicit is better than implicit). Most likely an error would also be raised if the default value violates the max_length property, e.g. 123456

   So you'll have to define the field by one of the following:

   ```py
   models.IntegerField(_('zipcode'), max_length=5, Null=True,
      blank=True)

   models.IntegerField(_('zipcode'), max_length=5, Null=False,
      blank=True, default=00000)

   models.IntegerField(_('zipcode'), max_length=5, blank=True,
      default=00000)
   ```

   and then make a migration (`python3 manage.py makemigration <app_name>`) and then migrate (`python3 manage.py migrate`).

   For safety you can also delete the last failed migration files in `<app_name>/migrations/`, there are usually named after this pattern:

   ```py
   <NUMBER>_auto_<DATE>_<HOUR>.py
   ```

Finally, if you don't set `Null=True`, make sure that `mode.zipcode = None` is never done anywhere.

Comment: What the requirement is to keep it as required field. Also here it is a integer field i am making a foriegn key and throws the same error. For more info my [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63661173/django-integrityerror-not-null-constraint-failed)

Comment: I am facing this issue, but if I use `null=True` its saving empty inside the database, where it is supposed to save the user id, when I remove the `null=True` it shows this error, I couldn't understand the problem, I followed the tutorial in django rest framenwork

Answer (score 8):

If the `zipcode` field is not a required field then add `null=True` and `blank=True`, then run makemigrations and migrate command to successfully reflect the changes in the database.

Answer (score 0):

In Django `Null=True` means Null Values are accepted. But Some Filed having Django that `Blank=True` are not satisfied for put Blank fields.

- DateTimeField
- ForeignKey

These two fields are used and if you want to put Blank I recommend adding *NULL=TRUE*

Answer (score -6):

Since you added a new property to the model, you must first delete the database. Then manage.py migrations then manage.py migrate.

Comment: For anyone that comes upon this answer. Note that deleting the database is NOT required when updating your models, it would be a giant pain in the butt, and is unlikely to fix the problem being discussed here.