# Null value in column "name" violates not-null constraint when adding new item in django admin

Tags: django, postgresql, django-admin

I have added a new model to my admin. This is my models.py:

```
class EngineeringToolAttributeType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    api_url = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    api_field = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

And the admin.py:

```
from extras.models import EngineeringToolAttributeType
from django.contrib import admin

class EngineeringToolAttributeTypeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ['name', 'description', 'api_url', 'api_field', 'active']
    list_display = ('name', 'description', 'api_url', 'api_field', 'active')

admin.site.register(EngineeringToolAttributeType, EngineeringToolAttributeTypeAdmin)
```

When I try to add (click on add button via the admin), I get this error:

```
Internal Server Error: /website/admin/extras/engineeringtoolattributetype/add/

IntegrityError at /admin/extras/engineeringtoolattributetype/add/
null value in column "name" violates not-null constraint
```

This has never happened before. I know name is not allowed to be `Null`, but I'm still adding a record. How is that possible?

Comment: Print out the name of the record you are trying to add.

Comment: Just to make sure, this is **before** you submit the form? Just clicking the "Add" button, so it should present you the form.

Comment: @JoshKopenI'm not trying to add any record yet. I clicked on button "Add" to bring me to the form.

Comment: @Melvyn indeed!!! before I submit the form. Totally weird!

Comment: Did you tried migrating for once?

Comment: @FazilZaid yes, it looks the problem is with fields called "name", because I have the same problem with other models. More a PostgreSQL I think

Comment: I have just ran the code in my machine and it works perfect. I too am using PostgreSQL. What's the version of your django?

Comment: did you override the admin form views in any way?

Comment: @FazilZaid 1.10

Comment: @BrianH. not at all

Comment: Please include the full traceback. Do you get the same error if you remove your model's `__str__` method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has a short answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25964312/not-null-constraint-failed-after-adding-to-models-py).

If you specify a field as not null field django will ask you to either provide a default value in code itself or it will ask you to provide a default value when you run migrations.
A better approach would be to provide some sane default in your models.py itself. After that run `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate`. You should be fine.

Answer (score 13):

This issue is partially result of not using `CharField` and `TextField` properly. You should **almost** never use `null=True` on this fields and their subclasses.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.null

> Avoid using null on string-based fields such as CharField and TextField. If a string-based field has null=True, that means it has two possible values for “no data”: NULL, and the empty string. In most cases, it’s redundant to have two possible values for “no data;” the Django convention is to use the empty string, not NULL. One exception is when a CharField has both unique=True and blank=True set. In this situation, null=True is required to avoid unique constraint violations when saving multiple objects with blank values.

I would highly suggest removing this param from your`CharField`s and `TextField`s.

Also just to be sure run `./manage.py makemigrations && ./manage.py migrate`.

Comment: in fact, name is NOT NULL (you can see it in my model), which is ok, but I get the "null" problem anyways