# manytomany filter horizontal didn't work django admin

Tags: python, django-forms, django-admin, django-cms, django-widget

Getting below error while add a field in *LabelLink*  model 
Currently I am working on django-cms and want to change current admin widget.

***IntegrityError at /admin/myapp/labellinkmodel/add/
NOT NULL constraint failed: myapp_labellink_links.sort_value***

models.py

```
class LinkPluginModel(CMSPlugin):
    .....
    label = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    link = models.URLField()


class LabelLink(CMSPlugin):
    ...
    links = models.ManyToManyField(LinkPluginModel,related_name="links" ,blank=True)
```

admin.py

```
class LabelLinkAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    filter_horizontal = ('links',)

admin.site.register(LabelLink,LabelLinkAdmin)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a forms.py and add this code. It will definitely solve your problem.

```
class LabelLinkForm(ModelForm):

  class Meta:
    model = Model Name
    fields="__all__"

  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(LabelLinkForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['links'].required = False
```

Answer (score 1):

Hie Somil,

> In this code, blank = true will not work. Please remove this and check.

Comment: yah , its working ...  but i want manytomany field optional ,how can i do that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25964312/not-null-constraint-failed-after-adding-to-models-py
Hope this will help you.

Comment: this link is  also not helping for me