# Django form_valid not passing params to CreateView

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

In my django project, I'm trying create a 'submit post' page using CreateView. It works, but with a dropdown menu for the author of the post. I would like to have the author automatically added to the post.

According to the (documentation)[https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/], I should use a form_valid method to add the author to the form. This does not work, even though it's copied directly from the documentation.

I've tried adding `'author'` to the fields in the PostCreate class, and that only adds the author dropdown box to the form.

Views.py:

```
class PostCreate(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Post
    fields = ['image', 'description']
    success_url = '/'
    template_name: 'post_form.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

changing to `self.author = self.request.user.pk` does not work, either.

Models.py:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField()
    description = models.TextField(null=True )
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

when looking at the debug error, I can see the author param is not passed, resulting in a `NOT NULL constraint failed`.

It seems to be the problem is with this line:

```
    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.author = self.request.user  ## The problem should be here
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

I've changed this line to the following, with no success:

- `form.instance.author = self.request.user`
- `form.instance.user = self.request.user`
- `self.author = self.request.user`
- `self.author = self.author.user.pk`

In all of these changes, the traceback always passes `None` to the params. This leads me to believe there is something wrong on another line.

Here is the urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from posts.views import PostList, PostCreate, PostDetail, Profile
from django.urls import reverse, re_path



urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path("accounts/", include("accounts.urls")),
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('', PostList.as_view(), name='list'),
    path('new/', PostCreate.as_view(), name='new'),
    path('posts/<pk>/', PostDetail.as_view(), name='detail'),
    path('<str:username>/', Profile.as_view(), name='user_profile'),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: Which error you got? Not null constraint failed?

Comment: See edited answer, it should be `template_name='post_form.html`.

Comment: The error is a NOT NULL constraint failed: posts_post.author_id. Here's the in the traceback, there's still 'None' where the author should be.

Comment: Have you tried the edited answer, and you have changed the `template_name` ?

Comment: Yes, the template name has been fixed, still same problem.

Comment: Restart the server, try to run in another port like `python manage.py runserver 3000` and hard refresh through `ctrl+f5`.

Comment: If that doesn't work then maybe some problem with migration files, can you also share urls.py?

Comment: Just restarted the server, ran makemigrations, migrate, same thing. Updated the urls.py above

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['NOT NULL constraint failed' after adding to models.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25964312/not-null-constraint-failed-after-adding-to-models-py)

Comment: Add `null=True` in `author` field then makemigrations and migrate.

Comment: I tried adding null=True to the author in the models. I *can* upload, but it uploads without an author. So that won't work.

I need to actually pass the author into the form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write `form.instance.author=self.request.user` as `form` contains all the instances after validation of form, so:

```py
class PostCreate(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Post
    fields = ['image', 'description']
    success_url = '/'
    template_name='post_form.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

> `Note`: class based views require their name to be written as model name as prefix and actual view name as the suffix, so you may it to `PostCreateView` from <s>`PostCreate`</s>.

## Edit:

I see a big mistake it should be `template_name='post_form.html`, you have used `:` instead of `=`.