# NOT NULL constraint failed error

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I keep getting this error: "NOT NULL constraint failed: users_userprofile.user_id" when I try to submit a form

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    #Esta linea es requerira. Linkea UserProfile a un User model
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)

    #atributos adicionales
    about_me = models.TextField(max_length=100,default='',blank=True)
    experience = models.TextField(max_length=250,default='',blank=True)
    offers = models.TextField(max_length=110,default='',blank=True)
```

This is the forms.py:
    from django import forms
    from users.models import UserProfile
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(min_length=6,label='', widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Password','required':'true','class':"form-control"}))
    username = forms.CharField(label='', min_length=6,
                    widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Username','required':'true','class':"form-control",'autofocus':'true'}))
    email = forms.CharField(label='', 
                    widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Email','required':'true','class':"form-control"}))

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password')

class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    about_me = forms.CharField(label='', 
                    widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'placeholder': 'Sobre mi','required':'true','class':"form-control"}))
    first_name = forms.CharField(label='', 
                    widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Nombre','required':'true','class':"form-control"}))
    last_name = forms.CharField(label='', 
                    widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Apellidos','required':'true','class':"form-control"}))
    experience = forms.CharField(label='', 
                    widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Experiencia','required':'true','class':"form-control"}))
    offers = forms.CharField(label='', 
                    widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'placeholder': 'Mensaje','required':'true','class':"form-control"}))

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields =('first_name','last_name','about_me','experience','offers')
```

This is the template:

```
{%extends 'base.html'%}

{%block content%}
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
<h1>Edita tu perfil</h1>
<form id='profile' method='post' action='/edit_profile/'>
{% csrf_token %}

{{profile.as_p}}

<button type='submit'>Editar</button>
</form>
{%endif%}

{%endblock%}
```

Thanks before hand

EDIT:

The error was in the views.py I needed to add an instance to the form, like this:

```
form = UserProfileForm(data=request.POST, instance=profile)
```

This is my complete views.py:

```
def edit_profile(request):
    try:
        profile = request.user.userprofile

    except UserProfile.DoesNotExist:

        profile = UserProfile(user=request.user)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserProfileForm(data=request.POST, instance=profile)

        if form.is_valid():

            form.save()

            return HttpResponse("Exito!")
        else:
            form = UserProfileForm(instance=profile)

    else:
        form = UserProfileForm()

    return render(request,
            'editprof.html',
            { 'form': form})
```

Comment: Can you elaborate your question little more clearly?

Comment: It seems that you have to submit `user` field when you're using forms. But without seeing your code for the form I can't say for sure what's your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem is that `user` in `UserProfile` is required, but you are not setting `user` field in `UserProfileForm`. The database didn't get `user_id`, so it tried to set null on this field, but the field had not a `null` constraint.  You can set `null=True` on field definition in `UserProfile` model, or overwrite `save` (or probably `is_valid`) form method to set user automatically or add user field to UserProfileForm, or whatever you want.

Comment: Thanks!, My error was in the views.py, i had form = UserProfileForm(data=request.POST) and added form = UserProfileForm(data=request.POST, instance=profile) and it worked, i thought the error was in the forms or something

Answer (score 0):

In your model give a null

```
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True)
    about_me = models.TextField(max_length=100,default='',blank=True, null=True)
    experience = models.TextField(max_length=250,default='',blank=True, null=True)
    offers = models.TextField(max_length=110,default='',blank=True, null=True)
```